# $\lim_{\kappa \to \infty} \frac{R(\kappa)}{\kappa^2}=\frac{12}{\pi^2}$

Tags: limits, rational-numbers, pi

> [*Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*- Joseph H. Silverman, ex 3.1]
>
> Given a rational number $x=\frac mn$ in its lowest terms, define
> $$H(x):=\max\left\{|m|,|n|\right\}.$$
> Let $R(\kappa)$ be the number of rational numbers $x$ with $H(x)$ less than $\kappa$. First prove that $R(\kappa)\le 2\kappa^2+\kappa$ and then show that
> $$\lim_{\kappa \to \infty} \frac{R(\kappa)}{\kappa^2}=\frac{12}{\pi^2}$$

The first part is quite easy since the number of choices for the numerator is clearly bounded by $2\kappa+1$ and the denominator is bounded by $\kappa$.

But, I have no idea how to proceed with the second part.

Comment: FWIW, the exact values of $R(\kappa)$ are given by OEIS [A171503](https://oeis.org/A171503) or [A326354](https://oeis.org/A326354).

Comment: Presumably the desired starting point would be $\displaystyle R(\kappa) = \sum_{n=1}^\kappa \#\{-\kappa\le m\le\kappa \colon \gcd(m,n)=1\}$. It's hard to help further without more context (where did you see this problem, what related background or skills do you already have, etc.).

Comment: @GregMartin This is Ex 3.1 of *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by Tate, Silverman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hints*** (with the risk of raising further questions). It's not too difficult to derive the recursive formula ($|...|$ - means cardinality in this case, not absolute value):
$$R(k+1)=R(k)+\left|\left\{x \in\mathbb{Q} | H(x)=k\right\}\right|=\\
R(k)+4\cdot\varphi(k)$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#cite_note-Wal1963-22). That's similar to [A171503](https://oeis.org/A171503).

As a result:
$$\frac{R(k+1)}{(k+1)^2}=
\frac{R(1)}{(k+1)^2}+\frac{4}{(k+1)^2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k}\varphi(n)\right)$$
Now, according to a result of Arnold Walfisz (search within the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)):
$${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k}\varphi (n)=
{\frac {3k^{2}}{\pi ^{2}}}+O\left(k(\log k)^{\frac {2}{3}}(\log \log k)^{\frac {4}{3}}\right)\quad {\text{as }}k\rightarrow \infty ,}$$
and the result follows.

Comment: You sure meant $x∈\mathbb Q$ in the first equation? The rest is fine though (+1)!

Comment: @SayanDutta, yes, that's correct. I will fix it.